# Constantly resetting minimum and maximum vales within a loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, variables

The program I'm trying to write is hypothetically going to be used by a bus company. The company has 18 buses and for each bus the user must be able to input how many people were on the bus via input boxes.

If more than 55 people were on the bus, the bus is classed as full. When the data for all 18 buses have been collected the average number of passengers per bus along with the minimum and maximum number must be outputted.

Here is what I've coded so far:

```
Public Class FirstBus
  Dim passengers As Integer
  Dim TotalPassengers As Integer
  Dim bus As Integer
  Dim FullBus As Integer
  Dim min As Integer
  Dim max As Integer
  Dim average As Decimal

  Private Sub FirstBus_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    average = TotalPassengers / 18
    lblOutput.Text = "Average number of passengers = " & average & vbNewLine & "Maxium number of passengers = " & max & vbNewLine & "Minimum number of passengers = " & min
    bus = 1
    min = 1000
    max = 1
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    For i = 1 To 18
        passengers = InputBox("Enter the number of passengers on bus number " & bus)
        If passengers > 54 Then
            FullBus = FullBus + 1
        End If
        If passengers > max Then
            max = passengers
        ElseIf passengers < min Then
            min = passengers
        End If
        TotalPassengers = TotalPassengers + passengers
        bus = bus + 1
    Next i
  End Sub
```

The issue is that when I input the data for all 18 buses, the average, minimum and maximum are all outputted as 0, I need to find a way of outputting these as the actual average, minimum and maximum

Comment: I don't know if those two method are in the same form but just looking at it, the load is executed before the button press. So you should also display the information after the button press.

Comment: Everything is all in one form , I've moved the load to the correct position and the code is fine now, I'm kicking myself for not picking up on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize before the button logic is done and display after the button logic is done.

I could look something like this:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    ' Reset variables
    TotalPassengers = 0
    bus = 0
    FullBus = 0
    min = 1000
    max = 0
    average = 0

    ' Get values
    For i = 1 To 18
        passengers = InputBox("Enter the number of passengers on bus number " & bus)
        If passengers > 54 Then
            FullBus = FullBus + 1
        End If
        If passengers > max Then
            max = passengers
        ElseIf passengers < min Then
            min = passengers
        End If
        TotalPassengers = TotalPassengers + passengers
        bus = bus + 1
    Next i

    ' Display values
    average = TotalPassengers / 18
    lblOutput.Text = "Average number of passengers = " & average & vbNewLine & "Maxium number of passengers = " & max & vbNewLine & "Minimum number of passengers = " & min
End Sub
```

The Load is only executed once when the form is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're not refreshing the `lblOutput.Text` when clicking the button.

```
Public Class FirstBus

    Dim passengers As Integer
    Dim TotalPassengers As Integer
    Dim bus As Integer
    Dim FullBus As Integer
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim average As Decimal

    Private Sub FirstBus_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        average = 0
        min = 1000
        max = 1
        lblOutput.Text = "Average number of passengers = " & average & vbNewLine & "Maxium number of passengers = " & max & vbNewLine & "Minimum number of passengers = " & min
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    TotalPassengers = 0
    passengers = 0
    average = 0
    FullBus = 0
    bus = 1
    min = 1000
    max = 1
        For i = 1 To 18
            passengers = InputBox("Enter the number of passengers on bus number " & bus)
            If passengers > 54 Then
                FullBus = FullBus + 1
            End If
            If passengers > max Then
                max = passengers
            ElseIf passengers < min Then
                min = passengers
            End If
            TotalPassengers = TotalPassengers + passengers
            bus = bus + 1
        Next i
        average = TotalPassengers / 18
        lblOutput.Text = "Average number of passengers = " & average & vbNewLine & "Maxium number of passengers = " & max & vbNewLine & "Minimum number of passengers = " & min
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show all buses in the `DataGridView` and update their data there.

```vb
Public Class Bus
    Public Property Number As String
    Public Property PassengersAmount As Integer
End Class
```

Then create collection of buses and bound it to the `DataGridView`.
In the Form

```vb
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponents()

    Dim buses = Enumerable.Range(1, 18).
                           Select(Function(n) New Bus With { .Number = $"Number {n}"}).
                           ToList()

    ' Add DataGridView control in designer
    yourDataGridView.DataSource = buses   
End Sub
```

When form opened write passengers amount to the second column of datagridview.
Use LINQ methods to calculate avg, min and max values.
Notice you don't need to have any private variables in the class for those values

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim buses = DirectCast(yourDataGridView.DataSource, List(Of Bus))
    Dim amounts = buses.Select(Function(bus) bus.PassengersAmount).ToList()

    ' You can create three labels for every output value
    lblOutputAvg.Text = $"Average: {amounts.Avg()}"
    lblOutputMin.Text = $"Min: {amounts.Min()}"
    lblOutputMax.Text = $"Max: {amounts.Max()}"
End Sub
```